# Can't get POP3 client to work

Tags: java, pop3

Could use some help with the POP3 protocol as I've never dealt with it before. I'm trying to programmatically download email messages from my yahoo account. For this I copied this Java class off the internet.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;    

public class Pop3Client {
      public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
          // mail server connection parameters for yahoo
          String host = "pop.mail.yahoo.com";
          String user = "myusername";
          String password = "mypassword";

          // connect to my pop3 inbox
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
          Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
          store.connect(host, user, password);
          Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
          inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

          // code to get the list of inbox messages
          .....
          inbox.close(true);
          store.close();
      }
}
```

It is always throwing a `MessagingException` upon calling the `store.connect(host, user, password);`. To make sure I wasn't running into a firewall issue I turned off the firewall on my Windows 7 system. I also tried getting email off my gmail account with same result, except with gmail it hung for a few seconds before throwing the same exception. I did enable pop3 downloading in my gmail settings.

Would appreciate some help. Thanks.

UPDATE:

I forgot to post the stack trace of the exception

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception MessagingException))    
    POP3Store.protocolConnect(String, int, String, String) line: 209    
    POP3Store(Service).connect(String, int, String, String) line: 295   
    POP3Store(Service).connect(String, String, String) line: 176    
    Pop3Client.main(String[]) line: 15
```

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Just updated the post with that.

Comment: look at this example: http://programming.mesexemples.com/java/email-java/javamail-how-to-read-yahoo-and-gmail-inboxes/ When this won't work, maybe you have to enable/use SSL

Comment: thanks. that was it.